# mobile subdomain seo optimization

Tags: seo, mobile, social-media

Hi we developed a site and just released a subdomain for mobile

- mysite.com
- m.mysite.com

we have different robots.txt and sitemaps for each so for a search engine they all look totally different although all the paths are sames. but is this a good solution ?

eg:

- m.mysite.com/apps/stackoverflow
- mysite.com/apps/stackoverflow

Is there anything to be done to match those site for google index and as well as to get proper facebook and twitter likes ? any meta tag ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394 google suggests to use canonical link on mobile subdomain pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John's answer pretty much covers the SEO aspect of it. If you want to combine the like counts for both the mobile and non-mobile versions, then you just need to use the same like button on both pages. The same thing can be done with Google+'s +1 buttons. Though the drawback to this is that Google will only treat the +1 as really belonging to the page whose URL you use for the button, and that's the page that will receive the SEO benefit.

Comment: Hi 
in that case do I need to modify each widget with proper unique link , or should I modify og:link meta tag ?

Comment: @altuure: Not sure what `og:link` is used for, but you probably do want to use `og:url` to specify one version (probably the non-mobile one in most cases) as the canonical version for Open Graph. I'm not sure this is required for implementing like buttons, but for maximum Open Graph support, you probably do want to use it.

Comment: does canonical helps in that problem ? assuming  that both pages with point to same canonical link ?

Comment: @altuure: That's an interesting question, but I don't think either Google+ or Facebook currently supports canonical--not that I know of at least.

Comment: I found this , which advises to out canonical on all mobile pages.. http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/v07dlTULfpE  

but in this case should I disallow all bots from mobile subdomain ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Google covers handling mobile versions of websites in this [blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/02/making-websites-mobile-friendly.html).

> For Googlebot and Googlebot-Mobile, it does not matter what the URL
>   structure is as long as it returns exactly what a user sees too. For
>   example, if you redirect mobile users from www.example.com to
>   m.example.com, that will be recognized by Googlebot-Mobile and both
>   websites will be crawled and added to the correct index. In this case,
>   use a 301 redirect for both users and Googlebot-Mobile.
>
> If you serve all types of content from www.example.com, i.e. serving
>   desktop-optimized content or mobile-optimized content from the same
>   URL depending on the User-agent, this will also lead to correct
>   crawling by Googlebot and Googlebot-Mobile. This is not considered
>   cloaking by Google.
>
> It is worth repeating that regardless of URL structure, you must
>   correctly detect the User-agent as given by your users and
>   Googlebot-Mobile, and serve both the same content. Don’t forget to
>   keep the default content, the desktop-optimized content, for when an
>   unknown User-agent requests it.